# XML Schema for version numbers

Tags: xml, xsd

I started [this side project](https://versionschema.org/) years ago. The goal is to eventually provide tooling that can process version strings based on the schema defined in an XML file (example provided below). I wrote this XSD to define a legal version schema XML file. In the process, I learned a good bit about XML and XML Schemas, but I am no expert, so I could use any feedback that you can provide.

Since I am actually starting to write the tools, I am experiencing some angst over the quality of this XSD. I want to make sure I've followed normal conventions and hoping the annotations I've included are sufficient for an expert to grok the intent behind the schema.

1. Have I strayed horribly from current conventions?
2. Are the annotations sufficient?
3. Is it self-consistent? Does it contain apparent contradictions?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all!

Working version of `versionschema.experimental.next.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://versionschema.org/xmlns"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsv="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" xsv:minVersion="1.1"
    xmlns:vs="http://versionschema.org/xmlns" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xml:lang="en" version="Experimental.0 {VSchemaInDev.0}"
    >
    
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd"/>
    
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
            Version Schema - Experimental.1 {VSchemaInDev.1}.
            Copyright and license: https://versionschema.org/LICENSE.
            Specification: https://versionschema.org/
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <!-- This file defines one root element (VersionSchema) and supporting cast of types and groups -->

    <!-- 
        Simple types in alphabetical order. 
    -->

    <xsd:simpleType name="assurance_T" final="#all">

        <!-- TODO {CBF5A103-9140-4910-AD5E-607DBD3B0284}: Convert to complex type and provide mechanism for users to annotate each assurance. -->

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                Applied quality assurance practices.
                Applies to the product on any change in the version representation (i.e., a version bump of any kind).
                There can be as many of these as actually apply to your product release gates.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">

            <xsd:enumeration value="undefined">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when no other assurances are proffered.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="reviewed">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when reviews are performed by experts, other than the changers, for all changes in each published release.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="static_analysis_reviewed">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when output from a static analyzer is reviewed and acted on for each published release.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="third_party_audit">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when a third party auditor or standards entity reviews all changes for each published release.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="tested">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when some testing has been performed for each published release.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="changed_features_tested">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when tests cover the changed features for each published release.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="50_percent_coverage_tested">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when 50% or more of product (code paths) is tested for each published release.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="75_percent_coverat_tested">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when 75% or more of product (code paths) is tested for each published release.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="100_percent_coverage_tested">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when 100% or more of product (code paths) is tested for each published release.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="third_party_tested">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Used when an independent auditor or standards entity runs compliance tests for each published release. 
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
<!-- Template            
            <xsd:enumeration value="">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">                        
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
-->
        </xsd:restriction>

    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="changeRule_T" final="#all">
        
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Rules that specify why a version field is incremented or changed.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        
        <!-- Change rules in alphabetical order -->
        
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="any_changes">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        The field is changed/incremented for all changes of any kind.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="arbitrary">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        The field is changed/incremented randomly or at the whim of bipedal wetware. 
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="back_compat">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        The field is changed/incremented only for backwards compatible changes.
                        Can be used as a modifier, for instance documentation_new_section may or may 
                        not be backwards compatible. Applying back_compat to the same field refines 
                        the rule set. Cannot be combined with any other rule that implies a breaking 
                        change.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="constant">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        The field is a constant, relative to the rest of the fields. It cannot be
                        changed independantly, but it can change if any other field in the version
                        changes. TBD: Whether and how to tie allowance of change to other named fields?
                        <!-- TODO {ABF2FD34-1AB6-462E-29D5-518D0D7503A7}: See TBD above. -->
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="fixes">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        Changes that fix bugs, refactoring, clarifying documentation, etc., 
                        without introducing new features or API changes.  
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="new_features">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        The field is changed/incremented only for addition of new features 
                        (modification of an API) without breaking backwards compatibility.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="simple">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        Any simple change. Can be combined with any rule that does not imply
                        high complexity.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="complex">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        Any complex change. Can be combined with any rule that does not imply
                        low complexity.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="documentation_new_section">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        New section(s) added to documentation.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="documentation_new_paragraph">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        New paragraph(s) added to documentation.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="documentation_refinement">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        Refinements to documentation.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="not_back_compat">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                        The field is changed/incremented only for none backwards compatible changes.
                        Used as a modifier, for instance documentation_new_section may or may not be
                        backwards compatible. Applying not_back_compat to the same field refines the
                        rule set. Cannot be combined with back_compat or any other rule that implies 
                        a non-breaking change.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
            <xsd:enumeration value="visual_changes">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        The field is changed/incremented for changes to images (icons, pictographs, etc) 
                        or the visual layout of the content.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            
        </xsd:restriction>
        
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="characters_T">

        <!-- TODO {C541A77A-D882-41E9-602D-DC6A616A19BC}: Annotation -->
        <!-- TODO {C1E6D8F7-0DA3-4FBB-1D48-30F8AFEE19B8}: This should be a complex type so we can use expressions or lists of characters. -->
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>

    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="dataFormat_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                Defines the data format. (string, XML/JSON/YAML).
                Only string is supported at this time.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="string"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="XML"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="JSON"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="YAML"/>
        </xsd:restriction>

    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="delim_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                List of delimiter characters.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>

    </xsd:simpleType>

<!--
    <xsd:simpleType name="docref_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Any URI pointing to human readable documentation regarding the parent element.
                If the URI is not fully qualified, it is appended to the content of the canonicalReference attribute of the VersionSchema element.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyURI"/>

    </xsd:simpleType>
-->

    <xsd:simpleType name="documentState_T" final="#all">
        
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve"> 
                Indicates whether the schema is a draft, living document, final or deprecated version.
            </xsd:documentation>            
        </xsd:annotation>
        
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="draft">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        The schema document is subject to revision.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="permanentDraft">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        The schema document is a "living document", subject to change foreever.
                        The state tag can never be changed.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="final">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        Except for this state tag, the document is no longer subject to revision.
                        The docuement cannot be changed, except to modify the state to deprecated.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="deprecated">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        The schema is deprecated.
                        The document is no longer subject to revision of any kind.
                        New dependencies should not be taken on this document.
                        The document may be removed from public feeds.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>
        
    </xsd:simpleType>
    
    <xsd:simpleType name="fieldtype_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                The type of the field being defined.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="alhpa">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        The field type is pure alpha characters.                       
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="alphanumeric">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                        The field type is mixed alpha and numeric characters.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="enumeration">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">                        
                        The field type defines enumerations.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                             
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="numeric">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">                        
                        The field type is pure numeric.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>                
            </xsd:enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>

    </xsd:simpleType>
    
    <xsd:simpleType name="range_T" final="#all">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                <!-- TODO {379E6FDE-98D3-4EE7-E5AB-7F5EA6A1239B}: Annotations -->
                <!-- TODO {E93FFC74-F167-49A4-8222-69E6D9B219A3}: Add pattern/restrictions for range notation.
                    Range should restrict the format to LowChar-HighChar, or use the set notation form [i,e), (e,i], [i,i], (e,e).                  
                -->
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <!-- 
        Complex types in alphabetical order 
    -->

    <xsd:complexType name="allowedstatetransistions_T" final="#all">
        
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                Lists the kinds of transitions that field value can pass through.
                TBD: Syntax/semantic definition.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:group ref="vs:ruleelementsGroup"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attribute name="allowParallel" type="xsd:boolean" default="true">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    When false, transitions represent a single track through the defined state machine.
                    When true (default), work may commense in or more phases simultaneously.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>
    
    <xsd:complexType name="all_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                All of the child elements, must be present in the version string or record, in any order.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:group ref="vs:baseelementsGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:controlGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:ruleelementsGroup"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ancestorSchema_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Declare ancestor schemas and transition rules. Allows seperate prerelease
                and release schemas to be related to each other by some simple rules.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <!-- TODO {FC722C21-5F03-44C3-CBB9-A2A90252B790} Expand on this! -->

        <xsd:attribute name="schemaURI" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    A URI pointing to the ancestor.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="anyof_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Any of the child elements, can be present in the version string or record, in any order.
                There must be at least one.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:group ref="vs:baseelementsGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:controlGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:ruleelementsGroup"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="xsd:occurs"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="anywhitespace_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                A place holder for any quantity of any kind of whitepspace, including new-line characters.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:attribute name="maxNewLines" type="xsd:unsignedShort" default="1">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Maximum number of new-lines allowed in a whitespace block. Default is 1.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attribute name="maxChars" type="xsd:unsignedShort" default="65535">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    Maximum number of non-newline type characters allowed in a whitespace block. Default 65535 (max).
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="field_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Designates a section of the version string or record that represents a named/referencable field.
                Fields contain a type attribute and any of the elements in the vs:baseelementsGroup, vs:controlGroup 
                and vs:ruleelementsGroup.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:group ref="vs:baseelementsGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:controlGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:ruleelementsGroup"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    The field name. Must be unique among its siblings in its parent element.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attribute name="inheritRules" type="xsd:boolean" default="true">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    When true, rules are inherited from the first outer node they can be found in.
                    No rules applied if not found in the chain of containing outer elements.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attribute name="type" type="vs:fieldtype_T" use="required"> </xsd:attribute>
        
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="literal_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Defines the presense of a string literal within the vesion string or record.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="caseSensitive" type="xsd:boolean" default="true"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="isExpression" type="xsd:boolean" default="false"/>
                <!--<xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:minmaxGroup"/>-->
                <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
        
    </xsd:complexType>
    
    <xsd:complexType name="oneof_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                One and only one of the child elements may be present in the version string or record.                
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:group ref="vs:baseelementsGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:controlGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:ruleelementsGroup"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="optional_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Declares an optional segment of the version string or record.                
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:group ref="vs:baseelementsGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:controlGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:ruleelementsGroup"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="sequence_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Declares an ordered list of elements.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:group ref="vs:baseelementsGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:controlGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:ruleelementsGroup"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="xsd:occurs"/>

    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="signedIntegerTransition_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Defines a transition type for signed integer numeric fields.
                Useful for count to zero from +/- starting point or anything else that needs a signed integer transition.
                You must provide a value for this type, no default is provided.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        
        <xsd:attribute name="changeBy" type="xsd:int"/>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="transition_T">
        
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Defines allowed transition states.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    Optional name.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
        
        <xsd:attribute name="to" type="xsd:string" use="required">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    Names the state transition target state.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>            
        </xsd:attribute>
        
        <xsd:attribute name="from" type="xsd:string" use="required">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    Names the state transition source state.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>            
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>
    
    <xsd:complexType name="type_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                Use to define types (essentially macros) to reference.
                Required for recursive definitions and also saves some space and typing.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:baseelementsGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:controlGroup"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:NCName" use="optional"/>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="typeref_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Use to reference a defined type.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:attribute name="ref" type="xsd:NCName" use="optional">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    The type name refered to.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    The name to use at the element scope in which type is referenced.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="unsignedIntegerTransition_T" final="#all">
        
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Defines a transition type for unsigned integer numeric fields.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        
        <xsd:attribute name="changeBy" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" default="1"/>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>
    
    <xsd:complexType name="versionmetatag_T" final="#all">

        <!-- Except for the sake of completeness, this element will be of little value.
             It is retained for version schemes that require the VersionMeta tag, but that's not
             enforceable until tooling has discovered the tag and pulled the referenced schema.
             I suppose a strict mode could simply reject the version string if after reading
             through the tag, we find that it's not placed correctly?
        -->

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Defines that a VersionMeta tag appears at the specified location in the vesion string or record.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:attribute name="prefix" type="xsd:string" fixed="https//versionschema.org/Schemas/">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    Defines default prefix used for all VersionMeta tags that do not begin with "https://" or "http://".
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        
    </xsd:complexType>

    <!-- Some groups used to define types/attributes -->

    <xsd:attributeGroup name="annotationsAttributeGroup">

        <xsd:attribute name="uri" type="xsd:anyURI">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    A fully qualified URL referencing human readable documentation for the containing element.
                </xsd:documentation>                
            </xsd:annotation>    
        </xsd:attribute>
        
        <xsd:attribute name="fragment" type="xsd:anyURI">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                    A URN that, when appended to the VersionSchema's canonicalReference content, yields the human readable documentation for the containing element. 
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>            
        </xsd:attribute>
        
    </xsd:attributeGroup>
<!--
    <xsd:attributeGroup name="minmaxAttributesGroup">

        <xsd:attribute name="minOccurs" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" default="1"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="maxOccurs" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" default="1"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="maxOccursUnbounded" type="xsd:boolean" default="false"/>

    </xsd:attributeGroup>
-->
    
    <xsd:group name="controlGroup">

        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="All" type="vs:all_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="AnyOf" type="vs:anyof_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="OneOf" type="vs:oneof_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="Optional" type="vs:optional_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="Sequence" type="vs:sequence_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="VersionMetaTag" type="vs:range_T"/>
        </xsd:choice>

    </xsd:group>

    <xsd:group name="baseelementsGroup">
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="AnyWhiteSpace" type="vs:anywhitespace_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="Characters" type="vs:characters_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="Delim" type="vs:delim_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="Field" type="vs:field_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="AllowedStateTransitions" type="vs:allowedstatetransistions_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="Literal" type="vs:literal_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="Range" type="vs:range_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="TypeRef" type="vs:typeref_T"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:group>

    <xsd:group name="ruleelementsGroup">
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="ChangeRule" type="vs:changeRule_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="EnumerationTransition" type="vs:transition_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="SignedIntegerTransition" type="vs:signedIntegerTransition_T"/>
            <xsd:element name="UnsignedIntegerTransition" type="vs:unsignedIntegerTransition_T"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:group>

    <!-- The one and only global element. -->
    <xsd:element name="VersionSchema" abstract="false">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve">
                Top-level container for everything in a version schema definition file. 
                There MUST be exactly one VersionSchema element per schema file. 
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="AncestorSchema" type="vs:ancestorSchema_T" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="DataFormat" type="vs:dataFormat_T" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="Assurance" type="vs:assurance_T" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element name="State" type="vs:documentState_T" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:element name="Type" type="vs:type_T" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        <xsd:group ref="vs:baseelementsGroup"/>
                        <xsd:group ref="vs:controlGroup"/>
                        <xsd:group ref="vs:ruleelementsGroup"/>
                    </xsd:choice>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:sequence>

            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="canonicalReference" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required"/>

            <xsd:attribute name="reportDefectsTo" type="xsd:anyURI" use="optional"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="organizationName" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="organizationURI" type="xsd:anyURI" use="optional"/>

        </xsd:complexType>

    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Example (Draft: SemVer.2.0.0.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VersionSchema 
    name="SemVer.2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://versionschema.org/Schemas ../versionschema.experimental.next.xsd"
    xmlns="http://versionschema.org/xmlns"
    xmlns:vs="http://versionschema.org/xmlns"
    canonicalReference="https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html"
    >
    
    <DataFormat>string</DataFormat>
    <Assurance>undefined</Assurance>
    <State>draft</State>

    <Type name="PrereleaseVersionTriple_T">
        <Sequence>
            <Field name="MAJOR" type="numeric" fragment="spec-item-4">
                <ChangeRule>constant</ChangeRule>
                <Literal>0</Literal>
            </Field>
            <Delim>.</Delim>
            <Field name="MINOR" type="numeric" fragment="spec-item-7">
                <ChangeRule>arbitrary</ChangeRule>
                <UnsignedIntegerTransition/>
            </Field>
            <Delim>.</Delim>
            <Field name="PATCH" type="numeric" fragment="spec-item-6">
                <ChangeRule>arbitrary</ChangeRule>
                <UnsignedIntegerTransition/>
            </Field>
        </Sequence>
    </Type>
    
    <Type name="ReleaseVersionTriple_T">
        <Sequence>
            <Field name="MAJOR" type="numeric" fragment="spec-item-8">
                <ChangeRule>not_back_compat</ChangeRule>
                <ChangeRule>arbitrary</ChangeRule>
                <UnsignedIntegerTransition/>
            </Field>
            <Delim>.</Delim>
            <Field name="MINOR" type="numeric" fragment="spec-item-7">
                <ChangeRule>new_features</ChangeRule>
                <ChangeRule>fixes</ChangeRule>
                <ChangeRule>back_compat</ChangeRule>
                <UnsignedIntegerTransition/>
            </Field>
            <Delim>.</Delim>
            <Field name="PATCH" type="numeric" fragment="spec-item-6">
                <ChangeRule>fixes</ChangeRule>
                <ChangeRule>back_compat</ChangeRule>
                <UnsignedIntegerTransition/>
            </Field>
        </Sequence>
    </Type>

    <Type name="Prerelease_T">
        <Optional>
            <Field name="Prerelease" type="alphanumeric" fragment="spec-item-9">
                <ChangeRule>arbitrary</ChangeRule>
                <Delim>-</Delim>
                <OneOf>
                    <Literal>0</Literal>
                    <Sequence>
                        <Range>[1,9]</Range>
                        <Range>[0-9]</Range>
                    </Sequence>
                    <Sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <Range>[a,z][A,Z][0,9][-,]</Range>
                    </Sequence>
                </OneOf>
                <Sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <Delim>.</Delim>
                    <OneOf>
                        <Literal>0</Literal>
                        <Sequence>
                            <Range>[1,9]</Range>
                            <Range>[0-9]</Range>
                        </Sequence>
                        <Sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <Range>[a,z][A,Z][0,9][-,]</Range>
                        </Sequence>
                    </OneOf>
                </Sequence>
            </Field>
        </Optional>
    </Type>

    <Type name="BuildMeta_T">
        <Optional>
            <Field name="BuildMeta" type="alphanumeric" fragment="spec-item-10">
                <Delim>+</Delim>
                <Range>[a,z][A,Z][0,9][-,]</Range>
            </Field>
        </Optional>
    </Type>

    <Type name="Prerelase_T">
        <Optional>
            <TypeRef name="Prerelease" ref="Prerelease_T"/>
        </Optional>
    </Type>
    
    <Type name="PrerleasePlusMetaTags_T">
        <Sequence>
            <TypeRef name="Prerelease" ref="Prerelease_T"/>
            <TypeRef name="BuildMeta" ref="BuildMeta_T"/>                    
        </Sequence>
    </Type>
    
    <!-- Put it all together -->
    <OneOf>
        <Sequence>
            <TypeRef ref="PrereleaseVersionTriple_T"/>
            <TypeRef ref="PrerleasePlusMetaTags_T"/>
        </Sequence>
        <Sequence>
            <TypeRef ref="PrereleaseVersionTriple_T"/>
            <TypeRef ref="PrerleasePlusMetaTags_T"/>
        </Sequence>
        <Sequence>
            <TypeRef ref="ReleaseVersionTriple_T"/>
            <TypeRef ref="BuildMeta_T"/>
        </Sequence>
    </OneOf>
    
</VersionSchema>
```